# Unable to Retrieve Setting Value for my Plugin

Tags: plugins, settings-api

I'm developing my first WP plugin, and I'm trying to use the Settings pages to create options for the plugin.

```
// add settings page
add_action('admin_menu', 'qd_button_admin_add_page');
function qd_button_admin_add_page() {
    add_options_page('QD Buttons', 'QD Buttons', 'manage_options', 'plugin', 'qd_button_options_page');

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}
function register_mysettings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'qd_button-settings-group', 'qd_button_color_list' );
    register_setting( 'qd_button-settings-group', 'qd_button_text_color_list' );
}

//Build out settings page
function qd_button_options_page(){ ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/includes/css/qd_buttons.css" type="text/css">
    <div id="qdButtonSettings">
        <h1>QD Button Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php"> 
            <?php settings_fields( 'qd_button-settings-group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'qd_button-settings-group' ); ?>
            <label for="qd_button_color_list">Color List for Button Backgrounds</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="qd_button_color_list" id="qd_button_color_list" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('qd_button_color_list') ); ?>" />
            <p id="instructionsText">Enter a comma separated list of the available background colors.<br />Example: Red, Blue, Green, Black</p>
            <label for="qd_button_text_color_list">Color List for Button Backgrounds</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="qd_button_text_color_list" id="qd_button_text_color_list" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('qd_button_text_color_list') ); ?>" />
            <p id="instructionsText">Enter a comma separated list of the available background colors.<br />Example: Red, Blue, Green, Black</p>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The settings page builds out as-intended. I can enter values into both created fields, save the values, and they are returned on the settings page.

When I launch my TinyMCE popup, I attempt to reference the settings values with the following code:

```
$mySettings =  get_option('qd_button-settings-group');
echo $mySettings['qd_button_color_list'];
```

This does not return the Settings value for the field 'qd_button_color_list'. In fact, it causes the php files to stop loading.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Remove the echo and replace it with var_dump( $mySettings ); That should give you a clue.

Comment: Same result with var_dump($mySettings); as the echo. Nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`qd_button-settings-group` is a settings group, not an option.

Use get_option for both items:

```
get_option('qd_button_color_list');
get_option('qd_button_text_color_list');
```

Comment: I placed this in my TinyMCE popup, and got the same results:

            echo get_option('qd_button_color_list');
            echo get_option('qd_button_text_color_list');